# How to fix collectstatic path error in settings.py

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up my application for production. I'm fixing my static folders, however I'm getting this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
You're using the staticfiles app without having
set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

The message points out the obvious error, however It's causing me some confusion because I do have `STATIC_ROOT` configured in my settings.py file. I'm assuming the error is then coming from a pathing issue.

Please check out my directory:
[image]

- Inside `/core`, you can see I have two setting files. I have already configured asgi.py and wsgi.py to account for `settings_prod.py`.

Here is settings_prod.py:

```
import os
from decouple import config
import dj_database_url

from datetime import timedelta


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['host_url']

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
          ...
       )


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'drf_yasg',
    'storages',

    # Third Party Apps 
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_extensions',


    # Apps
    'users',
    'bucket',
    'bucket_api',
    
    #oauth
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social_django',
    'drf_social_oauth2',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config('DJANGO_DB_NAME'),
        'USER' : config('DJANGO_DB_ADMIN'),
        'PASSWORD' : config('DJANGO_ADMIN_PASS'),
        'HOST' : config('DJANGO_DB_HOST'),
        'PORT' : config('DJANGO_DB_PORT'),
        'OPTIONS': {'sslmode':'disable'},
    }
}


db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = config('AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = config('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN')
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = config('AWS_LOCATION')
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'



STATIC_URL = '{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)




REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',  # django-oauth-toolkit >= 1.0.0
        'drf_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    )
}



# Custom user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"


# SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```

Pretty much stumped out here, how can I fix my settings to make my collect static work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<your_app>/static'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This modification worked for me:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```